# IOS: style.json file loaded, but the Google map is not displayed; only the pin is shown

Tags: json, swift, google-maps

I am trying to load a custom style to a Google Map view in IOS (swift 5.2.2 ). The code is shown bellow:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true
           mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
           mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.mapType = .normal
        
        do{
        if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension:"json"){
        
            mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
             NSLog("fstyle loaded")
        }else
        {
            NSLog("file not found")
        }
        }
        catch{
            NSLog("failed to load style")
        }
    }
```

I have a json file, that is working fine in Android.
The file used in the example is this one (but also with other, more simple files, the result is the same):

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#FFBB00"
      },
      {
        "saturation": 43.400000000000006
      },
      {
        "lightness": 37.599999999999994
      },
      {
        "gamma": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "weight": "0.01"
      },
      {
        "gamma": "3.36"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#0039ff"
      },
      {
        "gamma": "1.01"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "-4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "gamma": "2.27"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#251111"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#00FF6A"
      },
      {
        "saturation": -1.0989010989011234
      },
      {
        "lightness": 11.200000000000017
      },
      {
        "gamma": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#06dc8c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#FFC200"
      },
      {
        "saturation": -61.8
      },
      {
        "lightness": 45.599999999999994
      },
      {
        "gamma": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#FF0300"
      },
      {
        "saturation": -100
      },
      {
        "lightness": 51.19999999999999
      },
      {
        "gamma": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#FF0300"
      },
      {
        "saturation": -100
      },
      {
        "lightness": 52
      },
      {
        "gamma": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#0078FF"
      },
      {
        "saturation": -13.200000000000003
      },
      {
        "lightness": 2.4000000000000057
      },
      {
        "gamma": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The result is as shown in this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKF4A.jpg)

Also there is no error in the logs, seems that the style is actually loaded.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with your API key. Can you confirm if you are able to add your API key on your iOS application? Also, if the Maps SDK fro iOS is enabled for your GCP project? Another possible reason is that you might be using an API key with restrictions that is not compatible with Maps SDK for iOS.

Comment: Thank you! You were right, the problem is fixed now, after getting new API key. Unfortunately the error that stated an API key issue was shown on the console few minutes after map loaded (tried to load) - so I never saw it. If you can post this as an answer I will accepted as solution.